# Jackson deserialization into default subtype

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

classes AddressLocation and AirportLocation that are extended from Location. When the 'type' field is present in the json as 'ADDRESS' or 'AIRPORT', jackson correctly deserialized it into AddressLocation and AirportLocation classes, respectively. When the 'type' is absent, jackson doesn't know how to deserialize the object. Is there a way to configure jackson in a way that if the 'type' is not present or empty, use default type as'ADDRESS'?

//Removed getters, setters, and constructors from the following

```
@JsonInclude(value= JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible=false)
@JsonSubTypes({ 
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AirportLocation.class, name = "AIRPORT"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AddressLocation.class, name = "ADDRESS")
})

public abstract class Location {
    private List<Float> geoCoordinates;
    private String city;
    private String countryCode;  
}

public class AddressLocation extends Location {
    private String province;
    private String postalCode;
    private String streetAddress;

    public AddressLocation(final List<Float> geoCoordinates, final String city, final String countryCode,
                           final String province,
                           final String postalCode, final String streetAddress) {
        super(geoCoordinates, city, countryCode);
        this.province = province;
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
        this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
    }
}

public class AirportLocation extends Location {
 String airportCode;
}
```

The error that I get is -

```
Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class ***]: missing type id property 'type'
 at [Source: (String)"{"geo_coordinates":[1.17549435E-38],"city":"Whateverville","country_code":"WW"}"; line: 1, column: 79]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the similar issue when the JSON is sent by a client and Deserialized by framework such as controller. If that's the case, it's because the Framework managed Jackson is not managed by your code. You can either customize your deserializer through injection or simply control all instance initialization in your code through a transit object

```
@POST
public String createAddress(AddressLocationRequest requestObj) {

   AddressLocation address = new AddressLocation();
   BeanUtils.copyProperties(address, requestObj);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did write a custom deserializer, but it wasn't working. That was because I still had the subtype annotations on the base class. Works well after removing those.